# Socket.io disconnect event wrongly triggered for other users and after this they connect again

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, connection, disconnect

I have problem with the disconnect event in socket.io library for Node.js.
When I disconnect one user (close client app) the disconnect event is triggered not only for this one user but for all connected users. After this they reconnect again.

I would like to disconnect only this specific user. All others should be still connected.

As you can see below the disconnect event is triggered for those users in the same time and they also connect in the same time.

Yellow line is OK, but all below marked as red shouldn't happen.

[image: Socket.io events]

```
'use strict';
var events = require('./events.js');
var player = require('./player.js');
var moment = require('moment');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var uuid = require('uuid');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// all connected clients
var clients = [];

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("---------- SERVER IS RUNNING ----------");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.uuid = uuid.v1();
    clients.push(socket);
    PrintEvent("connection", socket);

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit("USER_DISCONNECTED", socket.playerID);
        var i = clients.indexOf(socket);
        clients.splice(i, 1);

        PrintEvent("disconnect", socket);
    });
});

function PrintEvent(eventName, socket) {
    console.log(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + "( " + clients.length + " ) " + eventName + " socketID: " + socket.id);
}
```

Few tech server details:

- npm -v : 5.5.1
- node -v : v8.9.0
- socket.io: 2.0.4

Few tech client details:

- Unity 3D + socket.io free plugin from assetstore

**Could you please help me?
I have no idea why it is not working properly.**

Answer (score 0):

It turnes out that the Unity3D plugin calles Socket.IO caused this issue.
When I tested the server code with client written in Node.js everything works correctly.

I also started to test the another plugin Best HTTP and I can confirm that it doesn't make this disconnect error. So far so good ;)